# Best practice for changing the columns' value after we fetch them from the DB

Tags: backend

Suppose that we have some data in one of the tables in DataBase we fetch them and then paginate them and other thing... if we want to change some of the values before showing the final results what is the best way to do that for example in freamworks like laravel?

should we create another array? and loop the data we have and push again to this array?

Answer (score 0):

That's one approach however there's another way to achieve the same result.

One way is to use the `array_map()` function. This function takes a callback function and an array as input, and it applies the callback function to each element of the array. you can use the  callback function  to change the value of each element of the array

Let say we have a array of fruits names assuming that is what your DB return

```php
$data = ['orange', 'lemon', 'mango'];
$new_data = array_map(function ($value) {
  return strtoupper($value);
}, $data);
```

the Output

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => ORANGE
        [1] => LEMON
        [2] => MANGO
    )
```